# Calling Async Method from an Async Method closes application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

I have an async Method (Let's call it Initialize()) which starts various other Methods using await.

Initialize() is called in a blocking way. My professor told me that I should make this Initialize() Method also async by creating a InitializeAsync() Method. So my InitializeAsync() Method now calls Initialize() using async and await and my Initialize() Method also uses async and await.

Problem: I dunno why but my programm starts running but closes immideatly instead of awaiting Initialize(). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
public Client(string ipAddress, int port, string name)
    {
        this.username = name;
        this.port = port;
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.status = Status.WAIT;

        this.InitializeAsync();
    }

private async void InitializeAsync()
    {
        await Initialize();
    }

private async Task Initialize()
    {
        this.users = new List<User>();

        this.SetupListenSocket();

        // Starting the listener.
        Task listenerTask = new Task(ListenEndless);
        listenerTask.Start();

        this.SetupSendSocket();

        // Starting the useriput sending.
        Task sendingTask = new Task(SendEndlessUserinputs);
        sendingTask.Start();

        string heloMessage = "cf-1.0:HELO:" + this.username;

        // Sending the helo message.
        this.SendMessage(heloMessage);

        // Starting the endless ping sender.
        Task pingTask = new Task(SendPingEndless);
        pingTask.Start();

        await listenerTask;
        await sendingTask;
        await pingTask;

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You never wait for `InitializeAsync`, and you actually can't as it returns void. Whats the point of `InitializeAsync`? It doesn't do anything but call and await `Initialize`.

Comment: I wrote InitializeAsync() so I can await Initialize(). The problem is that I need to initialize my stuff right after my class gets created and I can't use the await keyword in the constructor ... or?

Comment: `I wrote InitializeAsync() so I can await Initialize().` This doesn't make any sense. You're not awaiting `InitializeAsync`, so you still haven't solved your problem.`The problem is that I need to initialize my stuff right after my class gets created and I can't use the await keyword in the constructor ... or?` You can't, correct. You'd need to call the async function from somewhere else to await it or block synchronously on the async function.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm really stupid right now but that was the reason why I wrote the `InitializeAsync()` function. So I can await it. I don't know from where else I should call the `Initialize()` method ... :/ From where should I await Initialze async?

Comment: `I'm sorry if I'm really stupid right now but that was the reason why I wrote the 'InitializeAsync()' function. So I can await it.` Well the whole point of await is to wait asynchronously, which you don't want. `Initialize().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` would block and wait synchronously.

Comment: Ok I understand now why my program closes. So what is the solution? Delete `InitializeAsync()`  and  call `Initialize()` using async and await from another class after the client instance is created just like @Sievajet said? Is there no other way?

Comment: @StephanPillhofer Yup. If you're afraid that the devs using your API will forget to call `Initialize`, you can instead make the constructor private and expose an async factory method. For instance, `public static Task<Client> CreateClient(string ipAddress, int port, string name)`. Inside of it, you can call the constructor and await `InitializeAsync`

Comment: Ok, thank you all, that solved my problem and understanding of the right use of async and await :)